# Summation of natural number set with power of $m$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, sequences-and-series

Who knows about the summation of this series:
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}i^m $$  where $m$ is constant and $m\in \mathbb{N}$?

thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: How about [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HarmonicNumber.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look up Faulhaber's formula.  See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula.