# How to calculate $ 1^k+2^k+3^k+\cdots+N^k $ with given values of $N$ and $k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, algorithms, recreational-mathematics

Here $ 1<N<10^9$ and $0<k<50$

So we have to calculate it in order of $O(\log N)$.

Comment: See [Faulhaber's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65861/summation-of-natural-number-set-with-power-of-m

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18983/why-is-sum-limits-k-1n-km-a-polynomial-with-degree-m1-in-n and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65861/summation-of-natural-number-set-with-power-of-m and probably several others.

Answer (score 3):

Very interesting question, using generating functions

The multiply-by-$n$ operator $xD$, is defined by 
$$
  (xD)^k f \rightarrow^{ops} \{n^k a_n\}_{n\geq 0}
$$
where $f$ is a ordinary power series (ops) generating function for $\{a_n\}_0^\infty$. That means that $f = \sum_n a_n x^n $.

Begin with the fact that
$$
    \sum_{n=0}^{N} x^n= \frac{x^{N+1} - 1}{x-1}
$$

Then, apply $(xD)^k$ operator both sides of this relation and then set $x=1$, 
$$
    \sum_{n=1}^{N} n^k = (xD)^k \left\{{\frac{x^{N+1}-1}{x-1}}\right\}|_{x=1}
$$
By, example, for $k=2$, then 
$$
    \sum_{n=1}^{N} n^2 = \frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}
$$