# Series representation of $m=1^k + 2^k + \ldots n^k$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there any simple form for following question?

$m=1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k$

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula).

Comment: @AntonioVargas thank a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Summation of natural number set with power of $m$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65861/summation-of-natural-number-set-with-power-of-m)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula), for instance.

Answer (score 3):

As a follow-up to Lucian's answer, you might also like to take a look at the [proof of Faulhaber's formula on planetmath](http://planetmath.org/proofoffaulhabersformula) to see how those Bernoulli numbers manage to sneak into the discussion, since it looks like the Wikipedia article doesn't go into much detail on that point.

Short answer: It's because Bernoulli numbers are *defined* as the coefficients in the exponential generating function $$\frac{x}{e^x - 1} = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty B_k \frac{x^k}{k!}.$$

The crazy cool thing is that this generating function, and slight variations, crop up surprisingly often in various higher math contexts, so the Bernoulli numbers do too!

Here's just a sampling:

- [(Ir)regular primes and Kummer's work on Fermat's Last Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_prime)
- Special values of Riemann zeta: at [negative integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function#Negative_integers), at [positive even integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function#Even_positive_integers)
- [Euler-Maclaurin summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#The_formula)
- [Todd classes in algebraic topology and algebraic geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todd_class#Definition). (This and [Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirzebruch%E2%80%93Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem), it seems, is why Bernoulli numbers turn up in descriptions of the [image of the J-homomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-homomorphism#Image_of_the_J-homomorphism), [algebraic K-theory of the integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quillen-Lichtenbaum_conjecture), and the [classification of exotic spheres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere#Classification).)

Comment: Note: I'll happily remove these last (rather technically oriented) links out of my answer-comment if other community members think I should. This just seemed like a natural opportunity to draw attention to the fact that those funny coefficients appearing in Faulhaber's formula are quite certainly *not* just some sort of isolated curiosity.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449834/explicit-formula-for-bernoulli-numbers-by-using-only-the-recurrence-relation/450839#450839) interests you, Dan.

Comment: Ooh. Very nice. Thanks for the link, @Pedro!